# Use Xpath to extract the middle of a string

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML file with multiple  elements. I'm using XSLT to transform each  to a unique XML file. Each  has an id attribute that I want to use in the file name and I'm trying to clean up the attribute values. The ids all start with capi_ and some end with _output, so the format is capi_xxx_yyy_output or capi_xxx_yyy.

I can extract the string after capi_:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//section">
       <xsl:variable name="cleanId" select="substring-after(@id, '_')" />
```

From this new string, how do I grab the string before _output? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//section">
       <xsl:variable name="cleanId" select="substring-before(substring-after(@id, '_'), '_output')" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So for your cleanId variable, do you want it to hold the value xxx_yyy in the end?

Comment: yes, sorry, should have specified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried this but it didn't work:
>
> `<xsl:for-each select="//section">
>          <xsl:variable name="cleanId" select="substring-before(substring-after(@id, '_'), '_output')" />`

It works when the id ends with "_output"; it stops working when it doesn't. So just make sure it always does:

```
<xsl:variable name="cleanId" select="substring-before(substring-after(concat(@id, '_output'), '_'), '_output')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks good, you may simply need to implement an `<xsl:choose>`.

```
<xsl:variable name="cleanId">
    <xsl:for-each select="//section">
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(@id,'_output')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@id, '_'), '_output')" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@id, '_')" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: This answer makes sense to me but when I replace my line with the <xsl:choose> section, I get an error on each variable line: W [Saxon-B 9.1.0.7] A variable with no following sibling instructions has no effect

Comment: Also, I'm getting an error on a later line that says:     Variable $cleanId has not been declared. The other answer works, but I thought I'd report my results.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include proper variable scoping.  The variable has to surround the `for-each` so that it is scoped properly and can be used outside the loop.